# How to calculate an area of a conformal map enclosed shape?

Tags: plotting, graphics, numerical-integration

I need to calculate the area of a conformal mapping closed shape on the complex plane that gives the perimeter. 
I have the following parameters:

```
α0 = 0.2; α1 = 1.0; α2 = -α1 - α0;
u0 = 0.5; u1 = 0.2; u2 = -0.4;β = 0.0;
ax = 1.0; τ = 1.0 I; ay = τ*ax;
```

And the following conformal map:

```
Z[u_] := 
α0*WeierstrassZeta[u - u0, WeierstrassInvariants[{ax, ay}]] +
α1*WeierstrassZeta[u - u1, WeierstrassInvariants[{ax, ay}]] +
α2*WeierstrassZeta[u - u2, WeierstrassInvariants[{ax, ay}]] + β;
```

with this I draw the following shape:

```
B1 = 
  ParametricPlot[{Re[Z[u*I + ax]], Im[Z[u*I + ax]]}, {u, -Im[ay], Im[ay]}, 
    PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

So I have the perimeter of the enclosed shape, which is the conformal map. 
How can I extract the area of the shape on the complex plane, from the given perimeter numerically?

Comment: Naughty naughty.  Stack Exchange rather frowns on posting the same question on multiple sites - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358603/how-to-calculate-an-area-of-a-conformal-map-closed-shape-in-mathematica. Pick one.

Comment: This is the correct site for this question

Answer (score 4):

The conformal map part is unfortunately over my head, but see if the following might work to calculate the area enclosed by the perimeter of the enclosed shape:

```
ParametricRegion[Chop@{Re[Z[u*I + ax]], Im[Z[u*I + ax]]}, {{u, -Im[ay], Im[ay]}}]
Area@DelaunayMesh@MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeRegion@%

(* Out: 0.441419 *)
```

Here I generate a [`ParametricRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html) from your own parametric plot specifications. I then discretize it, which gives a 1D mesh (the perimeter); I extract the points from that mesh, i.e. the points defining the perimeter, then construct a triangularization of that region (a [`DelaunayMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DelaunayMesh.html)), then calculate its area.

BTW, I am almost certain that there might be a more direct route, but it is escaping me at the moment.

Comment: The last line of your code gives me the error: "DiscretizeRegion::defbnds: Unable to compute bounds for the region. Using default bounds of {-1, 1} in all dimensions". And Out: 0.289069. It is not like yours

Comment: I have made it, thank you very much.
I have change the default of  DiscretizeRegion from {-1,1} to {0.,0.01} so it is like this, 
b = ParametricRegion[{Re[Z[u*I + ax]], 
    Im[Z[u*I + ax]]}, {{u, -Im[ay], Im[ay]}}];
A = Area@DelaunayMesh@MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeRegion[b, {0., 0.01}]